# Powershell Task from CC.net

Tags: powershell, cruisecontrol.net, build

How do I pass in build args and environment variables to a powershell script from cc.net

I see the docs here : http://build.nauck-it.de/doc/CCNET/PowerShell%20Task.html

It is not clear exactly what the syntax should be if I have a function like

```
Function Concat([String] someEnviromentVariable1,[String] someEnviromentVariable2 ,[String] abuildArg1, [String] abuildArg2 )
{
 ///stuff happens
}
```

Could I do the following:

```
<powershell>
<script>dosomething.ps</script>
<executable>C:\program Files\PowerShell\PowerShell.exe</executable>
<scriptsDirectory>C:\Scripts</scriptsDirectory>
<buildArgs>-abuildArg1=2 -abuildArg2=3</buildArgs>
<environment>
<variable name=" someEnviromentVariable1"/>
<variable name=" someEnviromentVariable2"/>
</environment>
<successExitCodes>1,2,3</successExitCodes>
<buildTimeoutSeconds>10</buildTimeoutSeconds>
<description>Example of how to run a PowerShell script.</description>
</powershell>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll have to create a script that wraps the call to your function. In other words, create a file "dosomething.ps" in the `C:\Scripts` directory that looks like

```
Concat $env:someEnviromentVariable1 $env:someEnviromentVariable2 $args
```

Note that this assumes that the Concat function is in the scope of the script when it is run. You could do this by including it in your [powershell profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315342.aspx), or by "dot sourcing it in the script itself:

```
. .\scriptThatContainsConcatDefinition.ps1
Concat $env:someEnviromentVariable1 $env:someEnviromentVariable2 $args
```

Comment: Lets forget about calling the function for the moment. I will settle for the correct way of passing in build args and env variables.

Comment: @bearrito: Doesn't CC.Net do it for you?

Comment: No, I can't figure out how to pass in environment variables as either enviroment variables or build args. I am able to pass in strict build args but not env variables.

Comment: you are correct. CC.NET loaded all CC Env variables into the  into the powershell session.